# deploy different resources using deployment manager?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I'm planning to use the deployment manager to deploy a new project for each of our client.

I'm just wondering can I do the following using the deployment manager or put into script/YAML, so it deploys all components all at once through the command shell?

1. create a new GCP project
2. create a VPC for the client with custom subnet assigned
3. create a VM  and set the network to the custom VPC/subnet
4. create an app engine with different services using the yaml file
5. create storage buckets
6. create cloud Postgres SQL instance

What I tried so far, I can deploy the VM only through the deployment manager, I can do them individually using the command line, but not using the deployment manager in one single step.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Deployment Manager should work perfectly for this type of setup. There are a few minor caveats though.

1. You need to have a project in place where you can run deployment manager from
2. You will need to provide the deployment manager service account all the required permissions before creating the deployment (such as project creator at the org level). The service account is [PROJECT_ID]@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com

Next, you will want to call each of the resources individually in your deployment manager manifest, luckily all these resource APIs are supported by DM:

1. [Projects](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects) to create the project.
   ** All following resources should make a [reference](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/using-references) to this resource to create a dependancy so that DM does not try to create them before the project exists... which would result in a failure
2. VPC and VMs: use something like [this](https://github.com/Aahzymandius/deployment-manager/tree/master/working-env)
   ** This includes adding GKE clusters at the end and a VPC peering you won't need, but it demonstrates the creation of a VPC, subnets, firewall rules and a VM
3. [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions)
4. [GCS Bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets)
5. [SQL instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances)

As long as your overall config is less than 1 MB, you can place all these resources into a single config. 
If you are new to DM, I recommend trying each of these resources individually to make sure that you have the syntax correct. Trying to debug syntax errors with multiple resources is much more difficult.

I also recommend using the [--preview flag](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/updating-a-deployment#previewing_an_update) before creating or updating resources so that you can make sure that your configurations or changes will come into effect the way you planned.

Finally, you can either write all this directly into a YAML config or you can create templates using [either jinja or python2](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/create-a-template#writing_jinja2_or_python_templates) which can be imported into your config.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the Deployment Manager [Cloud Foundation Toolkit](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-foundation-toolkit/tree/cft-dm-dev/dm/templates) which is a sets of well designed templates.